# Moving Linux OS and all the connected HDDs/SSDs to a new computer (same architecture x64, different socket)

Tags: linux, cloning, migration

I need to migrate my entire system (Ubuntu OS and all the connected HDDs/SSDs) to a new PC.
The old one has an Intel CPU and the new one an AMD Ryzen socket AM4, so of course all the hardware will be different.

I don't currently any proprietary driver (I also used the integrated GPU and not a dedicated one).

Do you think it is possible that everything will be just by connecting all the SDDs/HDDs to the new motherboard?

Is there anything specific I need to think about?

E.g. what about the `/etc/fstab`? I configured it in the past in order to have specific names for my drives and some options like `nodiratime`.
What do I have to do with that? What about the `UUID` values?

**edit**:

here is my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
UUID=2c8bfb00-79b9-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003 /               ext4    noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=2c8bfef2-79b9-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-label/Disk1 /mnt/Disk1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,permissions,uid=1000 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/Disk2 /mnt/Disk2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,uid=1000 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/Disk3 /mnt/Disk3 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,uid=1000 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/Disk4 /mnt/Disk4 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Disk4,noatime,nodiratime 0 0
tmpfs   /tmp            tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777      0 0
tmpfs   /var/tmp        tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777      0 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks good to me. I can't see any problems here other than the potential one of a different video card.

Comment: hi @roaima, great thank you a lot!